# Windows 8.1 App to support TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2

Tags: c#, windows, httpclient, tls1.2, windows-8.1-universal

We have a windows 8.1 store app. For file upload/download with the server that supports TLS 1.1 & TLS 1.2, its not working. What library we can use to have it work using below or similar code.

```
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

Will "System.Net.Http" not support TLS 1.1 or higher? We tried using "Windows.Web.Http" also, but getting "Internal Server Error".

Please note that When we try to set the project target to .net 4.6, it automatically downgrades to 4.5.